# Class - variable declaration

Tags: php, oop

When the declaration of a PHP class variable we cannot perform any expressions, e.g.:

```
class A
{
    $a = 10 + 5;
}
```

only we can just provide constants e.g.:

```
class A
{
   $a = 100;
}
```

Can anybody knows why its like that?

Comment: Because that's how it is. Fortunately, you can call a constructor that runs your expression.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You cannot use statement or function, just a scalar value. This is because class variables are initiated in compile time (before runtime). Class constructor should be used to initiate property with statement/function.

Answer (score 31):

That is because expression is not allowed as field default value. Make use of constructors to initialize the variables instead.

I suggest you do like this..

```
class A
{
    public $a;

    function __construct()
    {
        return $this->a = 10 + 5;
    }
}

$a1 = new A;
echo $a1->a; //"prints" 15
```

Comment: What if the member is static and there's no need to instantiate the class?

Comment: good point @bigp . A(nother) reason why php sucks a bit it seems. Btw workaround is to use a static function... e.g. public static function getA(){return 10+5}

Comment: Question: "Why are expressions not allowed as initialisers for class members?" Your answer: "Expressions are not allowed as initialisers for class members." Hardly useful.

Answer (score 2):

**When declaring a class variable in PHP OOP, they are called class member variables or class properties.  The reason why we cannot assign values or perform  any expression or calculation is that You're declaring the structure of the class here, which is not the same as a variable assignment in procedural code.
The OOP PHP class structure is parsed by php Parser and Compiled, while doing this operation the Compiler  does not execute any procedural code. It can only handle constant values.**

As you already know  the following will not work and one gets syntax error.

```
class A
{
   $a = 100;
}
```

But you can achieve the same thing by using constant in class like this.

```
class A
{
    const a = 100;  
}

echo A::a;
```

If you need to do operations you do this by using methods or even class constructor if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can only perform **expressions** on Properties in `constructor` or `other member functions` of the class.

> Note that, you can initialize value to property outside of constructor
>   and member functions too. But It's impossible to make the expression.
>   The best practice is to initialize and perform expressions in
>   Constructor and member functions of the class.

Answer (score -1):

Well if it has something to do with initializing a new database name via "file.txt" which you refer through a certain path, what I did to resolve such problem is this:

```
class A
{
    private static $a = "";
    private function __construct()
    {
       $a = //Code to get the value and initialize it.
    }
}
```

Comment: What does this answer add over the same suggestion given multiple times three years ago?