# use entry in laravel 5 .env file to set the index in algolia search

Tags: php, laravel, algolia

I am trying to figure out how to write my `algolia` search index, in my laravel `.env` file.

I have tried using public `$indices = env('ALGOLIA');` But it doesn't work.
i have of course written `ALGOLIA=some_index` in my `.env` file.

So how can i make `$indices` accept a environment variable?

Comment: What happens when you do the above?

Answer (score 2):

The `.env` variables just overwrite the config variables.

Declare your variable in a given config file or create a new one (Google for a new one). Then you can direct to the `.env`ironment file.

`app.php`

```
'algolia' => env('ALGOLIA')
```

`.env`

```
ALGOLIA=123
```

You then call it with `Config::get('app.algolia');`.

Comment: I just tried your suggestion, but still no luck. I have identified it to be something related to this question:[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21941824/class-variable-declaration)

Comment: wait, you did it like this? `class Foobar { public $indecies = env('ALGILA');` ? Don't do this. Set the value in the constructor