# Syntax error when trying to access a value from static method in global variables

Tags: php, mysql

i am facing a problem here where i am trying to get a value in my class from another class static method.

My code is:

```
class DB{
        private static $_instance = null;
        private $_pdo,
                $_query,
                $_results,
                $_error = false,
                $_count = 0;
                $_operators = array('=', '>', '<', '<=', '>=', '!=');
        private $database_name = Config::get('mysql/dbname');


        private function __construct(){
            try{
                $database_host = Config::get('mysql/host');
                $database_driver = Config::get('database/driver');
                $database_username = Config::get('mysql/username');
                $database_password = Config::get('mysql/password');
                $dns = ''.$database_driver.':host='.$database_host.';dbname='.$this->database_name.'';
                $this->_pdo = new PDO($dns, $database_username, $database_password);
                $this->_pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
                $this->_pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, "SET NAMES ".Config::get('database/names')." ");
                $this->_pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                $this->_pdo->exec("SET CHARACTER SET '".Config::get('database/charset')."'");
            }catch(PDOException $e){
                die($e->getMessage());
            }
        }
}
```

it gives me this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp-php56\htdocs\backend\classes\DB.php on line 46
```

and line 46 is: `private $database_name = Config::get('mysql/dbname');`

any idea why i cannot do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When i put your code in my IDE, I get a syntax error

Expression is not allowed as field default value.

In PHP when creating class attributes you can assign a scalar value but not an expression (anything that has to be evaluated)

This link has more:
[Class - variable declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21941824/class-variable-declaration)

Solution: (note the semicolon after _error = false became a comma. Per @Edmund Dantes)
Assign the value in the constructor.

```
class DB{
        private static $_instance = null;
        private $_pdo,
                $_query,
                $_results,
                $_error = false,
                $_count = 0,
                $_operators = array('=', '>', '<', '<=', '>=', '!=');
        private $database_name;


        private function __construct(){
            $this->database_name = Config::get('mysql/dbname');
            try{
                $database_host = Config::get('mysql/host');
                $database_driver = Config::get('database/driver');
                $database_username = Config::get('mysql/username');
                $database_password = Config::get('mysql/password');
                $dns = ''.$database_driver.':host='.$database_host.';dbname='.$this->database_name.'';
                $this->_pdo = new PDO($dns, $database_username, $database_password);
                $this->_pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
                $this->_pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, "SET NAMES ".Config::get('database/names')." ");
                $this->_pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                $this->_pdo->exec("SET CHARACTER SET '".Config::get('database/charset')."'");
            }catch(PDOException $e){
                die($e->getMessage());
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

missing last {

```
class DB{
    private static $_instance = null;
    private $_pdo,
            $_query,
            $_results,
            $_error = false,
            $_count = 0;
            $_operators = array('=', '>', '<', '<=', '>=', '!=');
    private $database_name = Config::get('mysql/dbname');


    private function __construct(){
        try{
            $database_host = Config::get('mysql/host');
            $database_driver = Config::get('database/driver');
            $database_username = Config::get('mysql/username');
            $database_password = Config::get('mysql/password');
            $dns = ''.$database_driver.':host='.$database_host.';dbname='.$this->database_name.'';
            $this->_pdo = new PDO($dns, $database_username, $database_password);
            $this->_pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
            $this->_pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, "SET NAMES ".Config::get('database/names')." ");
            $this->_pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $this->_pdo->exec("SET CHARACTER SET '".Config::get('database/charset')."'");
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
 } <-------- this is missing
```

Comment: of course i have some other functions and it is not the full code only the required portion to see the error